# Inline Injection Annotation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

New to angularjs. I don't really get the [angular documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)'s explanation on the role of the [ **$scope** .... as an array. What does inline injection annotation means to this code?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the function in angular's DI inline annotation a array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656548/why-is-the-function-in-angulars-di-inline-annotation-a-array-element)

Answer (score 0):

This way of injection is useful for later code minification.