# Dependency injection in Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-directive, annotations, dependencies

Why is injecting a Controller in a directive done through `require` but other dependencies through the array annotation?

Comment: NM, I understand the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Require a Controller**

If you want to share the same instance of a controller, then you use `require`.

require ensures the presence of another directive and then includes its controller as a parameter to the link function. So if you have two directives on one element, your directive can require the presence of the other directive and gain access to its controller methods. A common use case for this is to require ngModel.

`^require`, with the addition of the caret, checks elements above directive in addition to the current element to try to find the other directive. This allows you to create complex components where "sub-components" can communicate with the parent component through its controller to great effect. Examples could include tabs, where each pane can communicate with the overall tabs to handle switching; an accordion set could ensure only one is open at a time; etc.

In either event, you have to use the two directives together for this to work. `require` is a way of communicating between components.

Courtesy of [Josh David Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691865/1575570)

**[How to require a controller in an angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691865/1575570)**

For the array annotation reason take a look at this stuffs

**[Why is the function in angular's DI inline annotation a array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21658756/1575570)**

Comment: thx maybe you could have a look at this one as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043665/passing-around-value-objects-with-functionality-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are never really injected into something else.  When you use require, you're just gaining access to other controllers on the parent element or current element. These "other directives" have to exist on their own on the same element, or parent element, hence the name 'require.'

Another way of putting it is, with require you're not asking for something to be passed in, instantiated, or created, you're just saying "I want that to exist on this element... and oh by the way I can access it in the link function since I know it exists."

Comment: by injecting something it becomes accessible in the link function as well right?

Comment: Yes, the 4th parameter will be a controller or an array of controllers,  which is confusing because it's the same mechanism that DI uses, but still not "injection" per se.